# Try to download mp3 with wget but it redirects to another site?

Tags: mp3, http, wget, redirection

I am trying to download mp3 files from this adress [hanialrefai](http://hanialrefai.com/) using wget like this:

```
   wget -r -l0 -k -p -A.mp3 http://hanialrefai.com
```

but it redirects me to http://quantsa.ru/?pw and then it say: **499 Request has been fordidden by antivirus ???**

why i am beeing redirected and where is this antivirus ??? [image: Screenshot using wget in windows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wget by default have something like "Wget/1.11.4" user agent. Site probably forbidden this user agent. So you should change user agent to browser like with "--user-agent" command:

```
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
```

Comment: it works but why the first time i was redirected to the site quantsa.ru which has a bad reputation ???

Comment: For me no error "499 Request has been fordidden by antivirus", so probably your firewall(antivirus) block all not trusted connections. Cause http://quantsa.ru/?pw redirect me to porno site. Question is why site redirect to this things without normal user agent. May be site infected or its admin mistake(?). Anyway better don't surf on this site.